# English translation of Corpus Hippiatricorum Graecorum

Tags: translation, greek-language

I'm trying to find a translation of HIPPIATRICA, Hippiatrica Berolinensia, preferably
an interlinear Greek/English version. I'm especially interested in chapter 20 and references to the Greek word "θλῖψεως" usually translated as "affliction," "pressure," or
"oppression."

Comment: Awesome Gareth! I'm still trying to locate an English translation of this text somewhere. I have to believe it's out there!

Comment: It’s not in the Loeb Classical Library as near as I can tell, which would have been the most likely source of a translation. It may not exist—it is a somewhat obscure text and late antiquity plus the veterinary topic makes it unlikely to be read outside of specialists who would probably prefer the untranslated text.

Comment: I love research, but I fear you're probably right as far as an English translation because of the highly specialized nature of this work. Thank you though for the conformation!

Comment: I agree with @D.A.Hosek: your project seems to have taken you to the point where you need to learn Greek to make progress.

Comment: @GarethRees It might be worse than that—with ed huff getting into meanings of obscure words and their references, he’s going to have to go beyond what he’ll get out of a mere reading knowledge of Greek, but he’ll have to get access to the TLG (Thesaurus Linguæ Graecæ). I suspect that the canon access would be insufficient for his needs and he’d need the full subscription access (hopefully through institutional affiliation since individual subs are $140/year).

Comment: Also, despite the name, latin.stackexchange.com also does Greek stuff.

Comment: Thanks to all for looking into this. On the basis of this thread, I'm skeptical whether the latin.stackexchange.com could shed additional light here but thank you for another potential source for future inquiries!

Comment: See also [Fischer 1979, "Two notes on the _Hippiatrica_"](https://grbs.library.duke.edu/article/viewFile/7061/4993) for a discussion of Greek vs. Latin and different versions of the _Hippiatrica_.

Comment: Also [Doyen-Higuet 1984](https://doi.org/10.2307/1291499) which has copious references

Comment: Thank you for those references. I'll definitely look into them!

Answer (score 1):

This is the sentence that you are asking about:

> Ἐπινενότηται δὲ παρὰ Σαρμάταις, ἔτι νεογνῶν ὄντων θλίβειν καὶ οὕτως εὐνουχίζειν, ἵνα μὴ τοῦτο συμβῇ.
>
> The Sarmatians are not [ἐπινενότηται], for they press newborn animals and so castrate them, so that this does not happen.
>
> <sub>[*Hippiatrica Berolensia* XX.5](https://archive.org/details/corpushippiatric0000unse/page/96/mode/2up). In Eugen Oder & Karl Hoppe, eds. (1924). *Corpus Hippiatricorum Graecorum*. Stuttgart: B. G. Teubner (1971).</sub>

A footnote gives the alternative reading περὶ θλίψεως πώλων νεογνῶν (for they press newborn foals) in manuscript g. The words θλίβειν and θλίψεως both mean “press, oppress, crush”, in context presumably referring to the crushing of the blood vessels and spermatic cord attached to the colt’s testes, a [technique still used today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emasculator).

I was unable to translate ἐπινενότηται, but in context it needs to be something bad that could happen if the horses were not gelded, for example “thrown” or “trampled”. There is a similar passage in Strabo which explains that the [Sarmatians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarmatians) gelded their horses to make them more manageable:

> ἴδιον δὲ τοῦ Σκυθικοῦ καὶ τοῦ Σαρματικοῦ παντὸς ἔθνους τὸ τοὺς ἵππους ἐκτέμνειν εὐπειθείας χάριν: μικροὶ μὲν γάρ εἰσιν, ὀξεῖς δὲ σφόδρα καὶ δυσπειθεῖς.
>
> It is a custom peculiar to all the Scythian and Sarmatian tribes, to castrate their horses, in order to make them more tractable, for although they are small, yet they are spirited, and difficult to manage.
>
> <sub>Strabo (c. 24). [*Geography* 7.4.8](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0197%3Abook%3D7%3Achapter%3D4%3Asection%3D8). Translated by W. Falconer (1903). *The Geography of Strabo*. London: George Bell & Sons.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your reply — so sorry for my late response as I've been on the road. The reference that started this thread — 2. [select] crushing, castration, “πώλων” Hippiatr. 20. (pertaining to 'θλῖψις' in 'perseus.tufts.edu') — was an esoteric link which lost me at a certain point but which you've very nicely cleared up mentioning this mysterious manuscript g. Again, thanks fo much!

Comment: @edhuff Can you describe your research and how it led you to the entry for θλῖψις in Liddell & Scott?

Comment: Gareth, I'd be glad to fill you in on my research. Unfortunately, I'm on the road again from KY., to Memphis, TN., today, so I'll catch up with you this evening. Again, thank you for your input! For the moment, I attended seminary and still translate scripture from the Greek and Hebrew. But the difference between NT Gk. (κοινή) and classical is like day and night. If I may use the analogy, the difference between 'blue collar' and 'white collar.'

Comment: @edhuff So you're looking at [Strong's Greek 2347](https://biblehub.com/greek/2347.htm)?